# using sed to remove only the last pattern matched on string

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to accomplish the following result

Given a bash script executed with the following parameter

```
#Input
./xxx.sh "\\\"P1\\\"\\\"P2\\\"\\\"P3\\\"\\\"P4\\\"\\\"P5\\\""
```

I want to remove the fifth parameter

```
#Output
# "\\\"P1\\\"\\\"P2\\\"\\\"P3\\\"\\\"P4\\\""
```

Doesn't matter with the fifth parameter is empty `\\\"\\\"` or not `\\\"P5\\\"`

I did the script bellow but it only remove if the last parameter is empty. And if I need to remove the forth an third parameters too, for example, how can I proceed?

```
a=$*

b=` echo $a | sed 's/[\\"[:alnum:]\\"]*$//g' ` 
b=` echo $a | sed 's/[\\"*\\"]*$//g' `
#the last try bellow give me the reasonable result when the fifth param is empty
b=` echo $a | sed 's/[\\"\\"]*$//g' ` 
echo $b
```

Sorry, I'm so far to be a shell guy

I got problems in ksh shell, but this works

```
b=` echo $a | sed -e 's/\\\\"[^"]*\\\\"$//g' `
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to do it using `awk`:

```
a="\\\"P1\\\"\\\"P2\\\"\\\"P3\\\"\\\"P4\\\"\\\"P5\\\""
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\\\\""} {$10="";NF-=2}1' <<< "$a"
\\\"P1\\\"\\\"P2\\\"\\\"P3\\\"\\\"P4\\\"
```

Comment: I got problem on another linux distro with this message: .sh: syntax error: `< ' unexpected

Comment: someVar==$(awk ' BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\\\\""} {$10="";NF-=2}1' <<< "$param_init")

Comment: You need to use: `someVar=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\\\\""} {$10="";NF-=2}1' <<< "$param_init")` not `==` after `someVar`

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
b=`sed 's/\\\\"[^"]*\\\\"$//g' <<< "$a"`
```